# RSpec/Capybara: Cross-Domain JS Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm working on an advertising application, where there is some cross-domain JS. I'd like to write tests that verify that the cross-domain JS is working as intended.

My first thoughts are that I would need to be able to

```
visit some_url_thats_not_my_rails_app
```

However, Capybara throws a "No Route Matches", since it obviously goes to only relative paths, and is intended for testing your OWN website. But I really need to go on ANOTHER page, and verify that things like the serialized token are identical.

Is Capybara the right tool for this? If so, what do I need to do to force non-relative paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Capybara is right tool for it. You can also use Ruby with Selenium webdriver(Would be awesome with page object gem) or Ruby with Watir webdriver.

To visit and test any web application, you can use Ruby and Capybara. For this you need to set app_host. Add this one in `support/env.rb`:

```
Capybara.app_host = "http://flipkart.com"
And in hooks.rb
Before do
  visit('/')
end
```

You can use Capybara with Selenium webdriver and you will be good to test any deployed application in production, staging or prep env.